# Communication problem between macvlan interfaces when sockets are bound to devices

Tags: linux, networking, network-interface, macvlan

I have a Linux setup where two macvlan interfaces in mode bridge are added on the same physical interface, in the same IP subnet:

```
ip link add link eth2 dev mvl0 type macvlan mode bridge
ip link add link eth2 dev mvl1 type macvlan mode bridge
ip addr add 192.168.42.16/24 dev mvl0
ip addr add 192.168.42.17/24 dev mvl1
ip link set dev mvl0 up
ip link set dev mvl1 up
```

I want to communicate between `mvl0` and `mvl1` using sockets which are bound to the interfaces, but this doesn't work.  For example,

```
# ping -I mvl0 192.168.42.17
```

doesn't get any replies. I can see that the kernel tries to do ARP on `lo`, but that doesn't work as it gets no reply.

- Is there a way to make this work, for example by manipulating routing or neighbor tables?
- Should this be considered a bug in the Linux kernel?  After all, `macvlan` interfaces in mode `bridge` should be able to see each other.

(*Background:* This is a simulation of two embedded devices running in the same process context. Our framework always binds sockets to interfaces, to ensure that communication really goes through the desired interface. Communication is normally via UDP.)

Comment: Yes, it is the same process.

Comment: I wanted to suggest to move an interface to an other netns (which would resolve all routing issues), but I can't see how an unique process would deal with this

Comment: Putting them in different namespaces would work, but this is no solution in the short term as our framework needs to be modified for that. To do this in one process you can temporarily switch the namespace while opening a socket, as the socket stays in the namespace it was opened in.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

(**Edit**: The previous version only worked for outgoing packets (UDP), this version works in both directions (TCP and ping).)

There are various gotchas for a setup like yours: Linux considers an incoming packet with a source address that matches a network interface address a routing error (because under normal circumstances it indicates a routing loop). Also, by default the kernel-maintained `local` routing table has highest priority, and that will prevent your packets from going out the interface it is bound to.

One can solve the second problem with policy routing: First, delete the overlapping routes (which will only cause trouble):

```
ip route list
# overlapping routes should look like:
ip route del 192.168.42.0/24 dev mvl0 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.16
ip route del 192.168.42.0/24 dev mvl1 proto kernel scope link src 192.168.42.17
```

Next, give the `local` table a lower priority (higher numerical value):

```
ip rule add pref 1000 lookup local
ip rule del pref 0
```

We need to accept incoming packets by sending them into the `local` table:

```
ip rule add pref 100 to 192.168.42.16 iif mvl0 lookup local
ip rule add pref 100 to 192.168.42.17 iif mvl1 lookup local
```

while all other (outgoing) packets to the resp. destination will use a special table that forces them out in the other interface:

```
ip rule add pref 200 to 192.168.42.17 lookup 100
ip rule add pref 200 to 192.168.42.16 lookup 101

ip route add default dev mvl0 table 100
ip route add default dev mvl1 table 101
```

In addition, we have to make take care of the first problem by disabling reverse path filtering (if not already disabled) and enabling packets that have a local source to be accepted:

```
echo "0" | tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/mvl{0,1}/rp_filter
echo "1" | tee /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/mvl{0,1}/accept_local
```

Now `ping` works even if not bound to one of the `mvl` interfaces. TCP and UDP also work, testing with `socat`:

```
socat TCP4-LISTEN:9998,so-bindtodevice=mvl0 -
echo foo | socat - TCP4:192.168.42.16:9998,so-bindtodevice=mvl1

socat UDP4-RECV:9900,so-bindtodevice=mvl0 -
echo foo | socat - UDP4-SENDTO:192.168.42.16:9900,so-bindtodevice=mvl1
```

Comment: Many thanks! UDP now works, so that will probably do. I traced the failure of ping to the socket not being in the `ping_table` in `ping.c`, for so far unknown reasons, and the last step of delivery to the socket fails. The default for `rp_filter` is 0 here, `accept_local` is indeed needed.

Comment: That comment about `ping_table` was a red herring. (`ping.c` handles *ping sockets*, which is a rather exotic feature of the Linux network stack. My ping uses raw sockets.) The actual cause of failure is that ECHO replies arrive on `lo`, but are expected on `mvl0`, so they are discarded.

Comment: That should be fixed in the new version, at least it worked on my machine with `ping`. If you use a different method for ping, please add details, so I can test.

Comment: Thanks again! It works, but the pref 200 rules look very strange to me, as they send the packet to the opposite interface, not the one having the IP address in the rule. But when I change that it doesn't work, so clearly I don't understand what is going on. More serious is that I don't see how this could scale to three devices, which is likely to be a use case here.

Comment: Yes, the `pref 200` rule forces an outgoing packet to use the *other* interface, instead of the local one which would be normally used. Without that, the packet would just be delivered locally, without going over the bridge. I've to think about how to do it for 3 devices. Don't forget that this method of pretending to have distinct devices by binding to interfaces is fundamentally broken, and we're just applying glue to make it somehow work nevertheless. Switch to namespaces ASAP.

Comment: It seems to be enough to send packets out to some other interface. I just tested it with three interfaces and made rules to send packets for `192.168.42.16` to `mvl1`, `192.168.42.17` to `mvl2` and `192.168.42.18` to `mvl0`, and ping in all direction works fine. Great!

Comment: That's somehow very assymetric, though. I tested right now with a *fourth* interface `mvlx`, and just send out *all* packets on this interface (it's enough if they appear to be coming "from the outside to the bridge"), but then the arp-table can get confused ... Maybe *pairs* of interfaces (`mvl0x` without IP addr for outgoing, `mvl0` for incoming) are cleaner... Anyway, it's a still a mess.

Comment: No, it's rotation symmetric. But it doesn't seem to matter, as long as the interface is not the one the address is assigned to. BTW, `accept_local`is no longer needed with this approach. Also, I have to check that packets can be sent to real external devices, a route for that seems to be missing.